# Swift Nsnotificationcenter post notification error

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, unrecognized-selector, nsnotification

I have a problem with post notification function.

In the `FirstViewController` in `viewDidLoad` I have this sentence:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "ponresultado", name: "resultadobusqueda", object: nil)
```

After that I have the function:

```
func ponresultado(notification:NSNotification)
{
    var oDato : oDatoSel = notification.object as oDatoSel
}
```

In second view controller of type `TableViewController` in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method I have this code:

```
var oDato : oDatoSel = oDatoSel()
oDato.id = "1"
oDato.nombre = "test"
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("resultadobusqueda", object: oDato)
```

I receive this error:

```
[App.FirstViewController ponresultado]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x797d2310
```

If in my `ponresultado` function in `FirstViewController`, I quit `notification:NSNotification` parameter like this:

```
func ponresultado()
{
    var oDato : oDatoSel = notification.object as oDatoSel
}
```

I don't have the error. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a : after the selector's name:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "ponresultado:", name: "resultadobusqueda", object: nil)
```

As your method is declared such as it accepts a NSNotification object:

```
func ponresultado(notification:NSNotification)
{
    var oDato : oDatoSel = notification.object as oDatoSel
}
```

Comment: Shai, Perfect... thank you so much. I don't see the : are missing... :-)

Comment: Shai, i dont understand you

Answer (score 0):

If your method takes a NSNotification as a parameter, you should add the ":" to your selector when registering. So your line :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "ponresultado", name: "resultadobusqueda", object: nil)
```

Becomes

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "ponresultado:", name: "resultadobusqueda", object: nil)
```